# Trying to compare two strings in XSLT and outcome is not coming as expected

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm trying to compare two strings in XSLT and wanted hard coded response as outcome

I have tried keeping an if condition in XSLT but it is providing me two results

```
<xsl:template name="variableTransformation">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiters" select="' /-'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nextDelimiter" select="substring(translate($text, translate($text, $delimiters, ''), ''), 1, 1)" />
    <xsl:variable name="string" select="substring-before(concat($text, ' '), substring(concat($nextDelimiter, ' '), 1, 1))" />

    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($string, 1, 1), $lower, $upper)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($string, 2), $upper, $lower)"/>

    <xsl:if test="$nextDelimiter">
        <xsl:value-of select="$nextDelimiter" />
        <xsl:call-template name="variableTransformation">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $nextDelimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiters" select="$delimiters"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$text='SELF EMPLOYED'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'Self-Employed'"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$text='SKILL TRADE'">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Skilled Trade'"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

input: 1. GOVERMENT 2. STUDENT 3. HOMEMAKER 4. PROFESSIONAL 5. SELF EMPLOYED 6. SERVICE/RETAIL 7. SKILL TRADE 8. UNEMPLOYED 9. OTHER

Expected:

```
Government
Student
Homemaker
Professional 
Self-Employed
Service/Retail
Skilled Trade
Unemployed
Other
```

Actual:

```
Government
Student
Homemaker
Professional 
Self EmployedSelf-Employed
Service/Retail
Skill TradeSkilled Trade
Unemployed
Other
```

Comment: You can try an [`xsl:choose`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_choose.asp) with `xsl:when`s instead of the `xsl:if`s.

Comment: @zk485 I have tried by replacing but now the output is Self Employed and Skill Trade instead of  Self EmployedSelf-Employed
 and Skill TradeSkilled Trade
Expected outcome is Self-Employed
 and Skilled Trade

Comment: @zx485 it worked forgot to inform Thankyou!!